# geom_histogram using proportions rather than counts

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data frame of length measurements for two species of fish across multiple years. This output of `dput` can be accessed at the link here

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzArRBVtzxttdUtaZWVoNUwzTFU/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT**

Due to the issue of accessing data below, I have added another link to the csv file. Hopefully this resolves the issue

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzArRBVtzxttZ2RlcDNKdUFERk0

**END EDIT**

I have then created histograms of length frequency for each species and year. If the data is read in as `fish_data` then the following code will be reproducible

`library(dplyr)
library(ggglot2)
library(scales)`

`colour_data <- filter(fish_data, Length >= 50 & Length <= 100)`

`ggplot(fish_data, aes(x = Length)) +
    geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 700, by = 50), colour = "black") +
    geom_histogram(data = colour_data, breaks = seq(0, 700, by = 50), fill = "red") +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=15)) +
    facet_grid(Year~Species) +
    theme_grey() +
    labs(y = "Frequency caught\n", x = "\nLength (cm)") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))`

However I now need to display the y-axis as a proportion rather than total count. So for instance, the height of each 50cm bin for each facet should be plotted as a proportion of the total number of fish. The total count for each facet would then add up to 100.

I'm having trouble conceptualizing how to do this new graph. I guess I'd need to manipulate the original data frame but I'm unsure how this would look.

Comment: My machine is failing to get your data, so I couldn't test. But try the following addition to your code: `geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)))`

Comment: Cheers. I added that code to both `geom_histogram` calls. However the resulting plot does not seem to make sense. Each facet is not adding up to 100

Comment: Found similar issue. It seems `..count..` aggregates all facets, instead of per facet.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

fish_data = read.csv("fish_data.csv", header = T)


ggplot(fish_data, aes(x = Length)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..) * 100, fill = Length >= 50 & Length <= 100),
                 breaks = seq(0, 700, by = 50)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('grey50', 'red'), guide = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=15)) +
  facet_grid(Year~Species) +
  theme_grey() +
  labs(y = "Frequency caught\n", x = "\nLength (cm)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: My issue with the above plot is that some of the facets dont seem to be adding to 100. Namely, most of the left hand side ones. Or am I just missing something?

Comment: When you say `the total count for each facet would then add up to 100` do you mean the facets `Fish1` and `Fish2` or `Fish1-2009`, `Fish2-2009`, `Fish1-2010`, `Fish2-2010`, etc.?